# I want to use PHP to query my current domain SQL server

Tags: php, sql-server

I have tried everything

Wamp and XAMPP only provide thier own local server and wont let me specify my own server

I have tried IIS and PHP but it doesnt work at all

I would like a simple way to get my SQL server to use PHP in my domain, i dont need it to be remote access yet

Appreciate some hand holding at this point :(

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you could give us a clue what you mean by "everything"? Did you read the manual? Try http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-connect.php

Answer (score 0):

Hi thanks for replying

I have explained below what everything meant by using xammp or want iis and php

The server I have is on the Microsoft SQL server management studio

All of the all in one installers will just user local Host and thier own server and database I want to use mine.

Whenever I try using MySQL connection it says it has activley refused connection.

I've added my credentials into the security section on the server. Allowed remote login and specified ports on the  server manager program.

Why isn't there a simple step by step program to enable php use on my server and or connect it to my online site..